# Outlook 2013 Auto-Reply with retained information from previously received email

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

Please see example email below:

> "We have tickets available for the following basketball game:
>
> Please email only me if you are interested and let me know which
>   section you want.
>
> Please be sure to make your selection carefully and only reply once.
>
> Basketball Game is on Tuesday 3/10 - 2 sets of 2 tickets. 
>   Tuesday 3/19/2014   Cleveland   7:30PM 
>   Section 101 Row K 16 – 17 
>   Section 101 Row K 18 - 19 
>   Section 124  Row K 1 - 2 
>   Section 124  Row K 3 - 4"

How would I auto reply to this email with a default response of one of the selected rows?

For example, I would like my default auto-reply email to state the
following:

> "Section 101 Row K 16-17. Thanks, Joe"

**Details**: I would like this to auto-reply to the sender EVERY time an email is received from the same sender. Basically I have to be the first to respond to an email in order to receive tickets to a basketball game. First come first serve.

Comment: ok great and um so? or "welcome to S.O pleas take the tour:http://stackoverflow.com/tour "

Comment: I have. Is something wrong with my question? Apologies if there is.

Comment: "outlook" and "php" are a strange mix. what form do you expect the answer to be in?

Comment: Is there a specific rule that I can put in place in Outlook? Or does this need to be coded? If it needs to be coded, what would the code look like in a VB.NET format?

Comment: as far as  i know there is no outlook rule for replying to an email (but im using an old version)

Comment: but as you tagged it php a) pipe incoming mail to script and process, b) imap to connect to mail server c) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA macro or develop an Outlook add-in if you need to get the code working on multiple PCs. The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

But the simplest way is to develop a VBA macro which can be run by the Outlook rule. For example, the rule may recognize such emails and run a macro sub which should be in the following format:

```
public sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  ' do whatever you need there
end sub
```

where the mail object passed as an argument represents the incoming email.

In the sub you need to use the following methods from the Outlook object model:

1. The [Reply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868875(v=office.15).aspx) method which creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message.
2. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) property which allows to set a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
3. The [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779(v=office.15).aspx) method which sends the e-mail message.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article in MSDN.